Can you use a Voyager Staff to teleport west multiple times at dawn?
The Voyager Staff item is as follows:

Staff, very rare (requires attunement by a spellcaster)
You gain a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic quarterstaff. While you hold it, you gain a +1 bonus to spell attack rolls.
This staff has 10 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 or more of the staff's charges to cast one of the following spells from it, using your spell save DC: Banishment (4 charges), Blink (3 charges), Misty Step (2 charges), Passwall (5 charges), or Teleport (7 charges).
The staff regains 1d6 + 4 expended charges daily at dawn. If you expend the last charge, roll a d20. On a 1, the staff vanishes forever.

Is the following sequence of actions legal:

Wait until the exact moment of dawn when it recharges.
Immediately cast the teleport spell, teleporting as far as you can see due west.
Now it will be a few seconds before dawn in the new location. (For instance, assuming the planet has the same size and rotation rate as Earth, the line at which it's dawn moves at about 1,000 mph west. So if you have visibility of let's say 2 miles, it will be a little over 6 seconds before it's dawn again.)
Wait those few seconds before it's dawn again, and have it recharge.
Repeat the above process as many times as you want (or until you get unlucky with your recharge rolls and don't have enough charges to cast it again), effectively "surfing" the terminator line westwards. (If you have two voyager staffs they will both recharge and you don't have to run any risk of running out)


That's a nice Gedankenexperiment, but I fail to see its practical aim...what do you seek to accomplish with this strategy?

@Eddymage To teleport farther than a single teleport spell could teleport you.

You should have clarified that in your question. Anyway, there are teleport spells that teleport you as far away as you desire, such as Teleport and Teleportation Circle. And Teleport is in the list of the spell contained in the staff...

@Eddymage - They might be fixating on the "very familiar" location spell condition, reasoning that they can avoid the high risk of mishaps and so forth by casting the spell multiple times to go to a location that they can see. But even if recharging worked the way that they think, this would be pointless—by the time they have teleported three times, their probability of avoiding at least one mishap or other negative consequence is only 0.42, worse than trying to teleport to a place known only casually. After five teleports, it is worse than only knowing the description.

@Obie2.0 Yes, I believed the same, indeed I've done the same reasoning with the probabilities.

“Recharge at dawn” items only recharge once per day.
This is clarified in Xanathar’s Guide, in a section addressing such items when no literal dawn occurs:

RECHARGING WITHOUT A DAWN
Some magic items can be used a limited number of times but are recharged by the arrival of dawn. What if you're on a plane of existence that lacks anything resembling dawn? The DM should choose a time every 24 hours when such magic items recharge on that plane of existence. Even on a world that experiences dawn each day, the DM is free to choose a different time-perhaps noon, sunset, or midnight- when certain magic items recharge.

Of course, if your DM wants to rule that your trick works, they can, but this rule is quite clear that “recharge at dawn” items are supposed to work once every 24 hours. This is further supported by the use of the word “daily” in the phrase “recharges daily at dawn”. “Daily”, not “at dawn”, is the frequency of recharge, whereas “at dawn” is when the once daily recharge occurs under typical circumstances.
